# Why does explorer.exe on Windows Server 2000 rise to 99% CPU when opening "My Computer"?

Tags: windows-server-2000, cpu-usage, explorer

I have a Windows 2000 Server machine and every time I try to open "My Computer", the CPU jumps to 99%  . I have to kill explorer.exe and restart it for the computer to resume normal operation (until I try to open my computer again). I installed the available service packs but am at a loss to how I might troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem on computers where one of the HDDs is failing.  If the computer tries to query the drive and can't all kinds of bad things can happen.  If you have multiple HDDs you might want to try disconnecting (either physically or virtually) all but the system drive to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any shell extensions installed on your server?  The TreeSize extension, for one, is notorious for this...

Also take a look at shares you have mapped, settings for A/V scanners and other monitoring type services you have installed.

Comment: Lots of admins touch this server, so I'm not positive if any extra shell extensions are installed. How might I check for TreeSize? Does it have an installation directory?

Comment: Also, how could mapped shares affect this (if no virus scan is set to look at them)?

Comment: Definitely worth looking for a misbehaving shell extension.  Try right-clicking in a blank part of your My Computer window and see if there are any context menu items there beyond what would be normal.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on people posts yet but I second squillman and Catherines comments.

When you open My Computer it will try and connect to all drives, HDD, CD-ROM ect. It also connects to mapped drives. I've seen where a mapped drive was slow to access or unavailable it would hang up for a bit while loading My Computer or Explorer.